# How to create an object for testing from external library

Tags: java, object, testing, junit

I have a class for parsing a json response given from an API request, that was made using the restlet framework.

The method responsible for reading the json takes an object from this framework, a Representation,
`public QueryResponse readResponse(Representation repr)`, and I would like to test the functionality of this

My question is, how do I pass a valid Representation object into this method in my JUnit test, considering I do not know how it is constructed from the API call, will I have to implement the call itself within the test to retrieve a workable object or is there another method?

Comment: Well, if you do not know how to construct a valid `Representation`, the best you can do is to mock it. You do know what your `readResponse`-method expects, so you feed it mock objects that yield these expected (and some unexpected) values to test that your method reacts as intended. Obviously, this cannot test whether it will work in practice - only an integration test with real `Representation` objects can test that the Framework behavior matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

For a unit test, use a mocking framework like mockito:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RestletTest {
    @Mock
    private Representation representation;

    @Test
    public void demonstrateMock() {
        when(representation.getAvailableSize()).thenReturn(1024l);

        ClassToTest t = new ClassToTest();
        assertThat(t.callRepresentation(representation), Matchers.is(1024l));
    }
}

class ClassToTest {
    public long callRepresentation(Representation representation) {
        return representation.getAvailableSize();
    }
}
```